# Error al iniciar uvicorn

Tags: python, fastapi

soy nuevo en Python y mas nuevo aun en fastapi (lo poco que habia hecho era con django), resulta que cuando quiero iniciar uvicorn (está chequeado que está instalado) me tira el siguiente error y no estoy encontrando por ningun lado la solución, el error es el siguiente uvicorn: The term 'uvicorn' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Otra cosa es que ya probe la solucion de agregar el link al path y nada de nada.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Vi que estás en la terminal de PowerShell. Usa
`python -m uvicorn main:app --reload`.